# LibGDX Pixel Jittering

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, libgdx

While working on my little game using LibGDX, I found a little annoying bug that drives me crazy!

Pixels are sometimes larger than others. This is especially noticeable when moving the camera and the player sprite is very small. As an example: the mouth - a single red pixel - jitters during the movement. If the camera and the player don't move, it can happen that the mouth is suddenly two pixels large.

I tried to set all position values to integers instead of floats, but it doesn't really work as I'm using interpolation (lerp) for smooth camera movement. Integer values for position results in stuttering movement.

The problem is that the value 1.5f is between 1 and 2, so openGL tries to draw both pixels (1 AND 2). This would be no problem for normal games, but I need pixel perfect textures because it's a pixelart game.

This image should try to explain it visually:
[image: The situation]

Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Comment: You could clamp to pixel borders after applying all transformations in the vertex shader. This should result in a smooth camera movement but without having the described problem.

Comment: Can you clarify: are you doing "retro" low resolution art? How are you managing the size of your camera? Using a Viewport class, and if so, which one?